# How do you build the underlying binary tree structure for a rope?

Tags: string, data-structures, binary-tree, text-editor

I'm reading about [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) on Wikipedia. There, for the string, "Hello_my_name_is_Simon", binary tree is given. How is that binary tree formed? Step by step representation will help!

Answer (score 0):

Most common implementations of balanced binary search trees (red/black trees, splay trees, etc.) support an operation called **join** that works as follows: given two trees T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> where all keys in T<sub>1</sub> are smaller than the corresponding keys in T<sub>2</sub>, and given a key x that's greater than all values in T<sub>1</sub> and less than all values in T<sub>2</sub>, combines T<sub>1</sub>, x, and T<sub>2</sub> into a single tree. The runtime is usually O(log n) for this operation, which is faster than might initially seem like it's possible.

Although these operations are designed to run on binary *search* trees, they work equally well for generic *binary* trees. If you build a rope whose underlying binary tree is a red/black tree or a splay tree, for example, then you can use **join** to concatenate text onto the end of a tree by creating a new internal node, then using the **join** operation to combine the two existing trees (and the new internal node) into a single tree.

The good news about this approach is that it runs very quickly (O(log n) time per concatenation) and that it keeps the trees balanced. The bad news is that **join** can be tricky to implement. The logic to **join** two red/black trees is quite tricky. Fortunately, splay trees have pretty easy logic for **join**, so one simple option to get fast ropes would be to use splay trees as the underlying tree structure.